# Is there a Variadic Version of either (R.either)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, variadic-functions, ramda.js

I have a need for a variadic version of `R.either`. After doing some searching around the web, I have not found a solution. `R.anyPass` would work but it returns a Boolean instead of the original value. Is there already a solution that I have overlooked? If not, what would be the most optimal way to write a variadic either utility function?

An example:

```
const test = variadicEither(R.multiply(0), R.add(-1), R.add(1), R.add(2))
test(1) // => 2
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what output you want if there is no match.  but would this do: `const varEither = (...fns) => (x, res = null, fn = fns.find(fn => res = fn(x))) => res` ? It should run each function once until it hits a truthy result, returning that, or return the result of the last function.  Is that what you want?

Comment: The above does satisfy all requirements. I suggest submitting it as an answer so it can be considered for the best implementation.

Comment: added it.  But I personally prefer the updated answer from customcommander, at least if you're already using Ramda in your code.

Comment: As a side concern, which name would be most appropriate for a variadic or array accepting either?  Some that come to mind: eitherV, varEither, eitherAny, anyEither. Thoughts?

Comment: You know what they say, right:  The two hardest problems in software are cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: @webstermath I would really like for your question to be updated to show an example use of such a function and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Should Ramda be petitioned to include an official variadic either in its library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of `reduce` + `reduced`:

```js
const z = (...fns) => x => reduce((res, fn) => res ? reduced(res) : fn(x), false, fns);

console.log(
  z(always(0), always(10), always(2))(11),
  z(always(0), always(''), always(15), always(2))(11),
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {reduce, reduced, always} = R;</script>
```

---

*(previous attempt)*

I would do something like this:

```js
const z = unapply(curry((fns, x) => find(applyTo(x), fns)(x)));

console.log(

  z(always(0), always(15), always(2))(10),
  z(always(0), always(''), always(NaN), always(30), always(2))(10),

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {unapply, curry, find, applyTo, always} = R;</script>
```

There are three main caveats to this though!

1. You have to call `z` in two "passes", i.e. `z(...functions)(x)`
2. Although it should be easy to add, I didn't care about the case where no function "matches"
3. Perhaps not a big deal but worth noting: a matching predicate will be executed twice

Comment: Thanks, for the solution.  However, I do need a solution that calls each function at most once.  Also if there are only two functions passed in or none of the functions return a truthy response, the solution above gives the error: `find(...) is not a function`

Comment: @webstermath Yep I'm aware that's the case #2 in my original attempt. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, your new solution does satisfy all requirements and I do like the implementation.  However, as there are now several solutions that satisfy all requirements of a variadic either, I am going to wait for some more up votes to help me decide which one to accept.

Comment: nice application of transducer techniques

Answer (score 3):

**Without Ramda ...**

I'd probably write this using simple recursion -

```js
const always = x =>
  _ => x

const identity = x =>
  x

const veither = (f = identity, ...more) => (...args) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? f (...args)
    : f (...args) || veither (...more) (...args)

const test =
  veither
    ( always (0)
    , always (false)
    , always ("")
    , always (1)
    , always (true)
    )

console .log (test ())
// 1
```

**But there's more to it ...**

`R.either` has to be one the more eccentric functions in the Ramda library. If you read the [documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either) closely, `R.either` has two (2) behaviour variants: it can return -

1. a function that that passes its argument to each of the two functions, `f` and `g`, and returns the first *truthy* value - `g` will *not* be evaluated if `f`'s result is truthy.
2. Or, an applicative functor

The signature for `R.either` says -

```
either : (*… → Boolean) → (*… → Boolean) → (*… → Boolean)
```

But that's definitely fudging it a bit. For our two cases above, the following two signatures are much closer -

```
// variant 1
either : (*… → a) → (*… → b) → (*… → a|b)

// variant 2
either : Apply f => f a → f b → f (a|b)
```

Let's confirm these two variants with simple tests -

```js
const { always, either } =
  R

const { Just, Nothing } =
  folktale.maybe

// variant 1 returns a function
const test =
  either
    ( always (0)
    , always (true)
    )

console.log(test()) // => true

// variant 2 returns an applicative functor
const result =
  either
    ( Just (false)
    , Just (1)
    )

console.log(result) // => Just { 1 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/folktale/2.0.1/folktale.min.js"></script>
```

**Double down ...**

Now let's make a super-powered `veither` that offers the same dual capability as `R.either` -

```js
const vor = (a, ...more) =>
  a || vor (...more)

const veither = (f, ...more) =>
  f instanceof Function
    // variant 1
    ? (...args) =>
        f (...args) || veither (...more) (...args)
    // variant 2
    : liftN (more.length + 1, vor) (f, ...more)
```

It works just like `R.either` except now it accepts two *or more* arguments. Behaviour of each variant is upheld -

```js
// variant 1 returns a function
const test =
  veither
    ( always (false)
    , always (0)
    , always ("fn")
    , always (2)
    )

test () // => "fn"

// variant 2 returns an applicative functor
veither
  ( Just (0)
  , Just (false)
  , Just ("")
  , Just ("ap")
  , Just (2)
  )
  // => Just { "ap" }
```

You can [view the source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/either.js#L37-L43) for `R.either` and compare it with `veither` above. Uncurried and restyled, you can see its many similarities here -

```js
// either : (*… → a) → (*… → b) → (*… → a|b)

// either : Apply f => f a -> f b -> f (a|b)

const either = (f, g) =>
  isFunction (f)
    // variant 1
    ? (...args) =>
        f (...args) || g (...args)
    // variant 2
    : lift (or) (f, g)
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const { always, either, liftN } =
  R

const { Just, Nothing } =
  folktale.maybe

const vor = (a, ...more) =>
  a || vor (...more)

const veither = (f, ...more) =>
  f instanceof Function
    ? (...args) =>
        f (...args) || veither (...more) (...args)
    : liftN (more.length + 1, vor) (f, ...more)

// variant 1 returns a function
const test =
  veither
    ( always (false)
    , always (0)
    , always ("fn")
    , always (2)
    )

console .log (test ()) // "fn"

// variant 2 returns an applicative functor
const result =
  veither
    ( Just (0)
    , Just (false)
    , Just ("")
    , Just ("ap")
    , Just (2)
    )

console .log (result) // Just { "ap" }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/folktale/2.0.1/folktale.min.js"></script>
```

**With hindsight *and* foresight ...**

With one little trick, we can skip all the ceremony of reasoning about our own `veither`. In this implementation, we simply make a recurring call to `R.either` -

```js
const veither = (f, ...more) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? R.either (f, f) // ^_^
    : R.either (f, veither (...more))
```

I show you this because it works nicely and preserves the behaviour of both variants, but it should be avoided because it builds a much more complex tree of computations. Nevertheless, expand the snippet below to verify it works -

```js
const { always, either } =
  R

const { Just, Nothing } =
  folktale.maybe

const veither = (f, ...more) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? either (f, f)
    : either (f, veither (...more))

// variant 1 returns a function
const test =
  veither
    ( always (false)
    , always (0)
    , always ("fn")
    , always (2)
    )

console .log (test ()) // "fn"

// variant 2 returns an applicative functor
const result =
  veither
    ( Just (0)
    , Just (false)
    , Just ("")
    , Just ("ap")
    , Just (2)
    )

console .log (result) // Just { "ap" }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/folktale/2.0.1/folktale.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent and informative answer!  Really felt I learned a lot not just about 'either' but Ramda and functional programming in general.  This does seem like a great solution and possibly the solution.  I just want to see if others agree.  Furthermore, it looks like your vote is for the name 'veither', no?

Comment: @webstermath, I'm really happy to help. Ramda has many other variadic functions so I'm not sure why `R.either` in particular is limited to just two arguments. This function is particularly difficult to give a name to though because the behaviour is very complex and it does different things depending on the inputs. A better design would probably separate the two variants and give each of them a unique name, imo.

Comment: On second thought, I don't know why the applicative behaviour is here at all. Having a library function as a shortcut for `R.lift(R.or)` is basically saving you nothing at the cost of tremendous complexity. If you have functions, use `R.either(f,g)(x)` – if you have applicative functors, you would instead use `R.lift(R.or)(f,g)`. I don't use Ramda in practice, so I don't know how many people rely on the dual behaviour of `R.either`. Based on the other answers here, I would be surprised if others are even aware of the applicative variant.

Comment: I honestly don't recall why `either` got the behavior it did.  There was a fair bit of early churn around the functions like `or`/`either`, `and`/`both`.  I honestly doubt that it's used much in this case.  But many of our other functions, which operate on various types do make sense.  We supply implementations of `map`, for instance, for arrays, objects, and functions, and delegate to object methods for other Functors.  This makes sense to me.  `either`, not so much.  I would probably reach for `lift(or)` before remembering that `either` has that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

I personally prefer the previous version, it is much more cleaner, but you could eventually ramdify it even more (you cannot write it entirely point-free due to the recursion):

```js
const either = (...fns) => R.converge(R.either, [
  R.head,
  R.pipe(
    R.tail,
    R.ifElse(R.isEmpty, R.identity, R.apply(either)),
  ),
])(fns);

const result = either(R.always(null), R.always(0), R.always('truthy'))();

console.log(`result is "${result}"`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

#### Update:

as per @customcommander's suggestion, recursion may be nested in the right branch to have a much cleaner script...

```js
const either = (...fns) => (...values) => {
  const [left = R.identity, ...rest] = fns;
  
  return R.either(
    left, 
    rest.length ? either(...rest) : R.identity,
  )(...values);
}

const result = either(R.always(null), R.always(0), R.always('truthy'))();

console.log(`result is "${result}"`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

---

You could possibly call `R.either` recursively...

```js
const either = (...fns) => (...values) => {
  const [left = R.identity, right = R.identity, ...rest] = fns;
  
  return R.either(left, right)(...values) || (
    rest.length ? either(...rest)(...values) : null
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: That’s interesting. I wonder if you could nest your recursion in the right branch of an outer `R.either`. e.g. `R.either(R.either(...), either(...))`

Comment: definitely doable, it also makes the script easier to read and maintain. Great suggestion!

Comment: Thanks @Hitmands.  This is a great solution.  It is now even harder for me to choose which solution to accept.  I am looking for up votes and comments to argue for which solution is most consistent with functional/Ramda principles before I choose.

Comment: well, then I hope you don't mind if I complicate your choice even more by adding another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The 1st function `findTruthyFn` is used to find a truty function or take the last function if none of them return a truthy result.

The 2nd function `fn` gets a list of functions, and the value, uses `findTruthyFn` to find the function, and apply it to the value to get the result.

```js
const { either, pipe, applyTo, flip, find, always, last, converge, call, identity } = R

const findTruthyFn = fns => either(
  pipe(applyTo, flip(find)(fns)), 
  always(last(fns))
)

const fn = fns => converge(call, [findTruthyFn(fns), identity])

const check = fn([x => x + 1, x => x - 1])

console.log(check(1))
console.log(check(-1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

If you want to limit the number of calls to of matching functions to one, you can memoize the functions before testing them:

```js
const { either, pipe, applyTo, flip, find, always, last, converge, call, identity, map, memoizeWith } = R

const findTruthyFn = fns => either(
  pipe(applyTo, flip(find)(map(memoizeWith(identity), fns))), 
  always(last(fns))
)

const fn = fns => converge(call, [findTruthyFn(fns), identity])

const check = fn([
  x => console.log('1st called') || x + 1, 
  x => console.log('2nd called') || x - 1
])

console.log(check(1))
console.log(check(-1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I tested it and it does work.  However, it calls the matching predicate twice and I need for each function to be called at most once.

Comment: We can memoize the functions to limit the number of calls to one. See update.

Answer (score 1):

This (non-Ramda) version is quite simple, and it seems to do what's needed:

```js
const varEither = (...fns) => (x, res = null, fn = fns.find(fn => res = fn(x))) => res
```

If you need to supply multiple parameters to the resulting function, it wouldn't be much harder:

```js
const varEither = (...fns) => (...xs) => {
  let res = null;
  fns .find (fn => res = fn (...xs) )
  return res;
}
```

But I've got to say calling `fns.find` for its side-effects does seem quite dirty, which might make me choose customcommander's updated version instead of this.

Comment: but what about the applicative functors? ^_^